# Using Access Token to like a comment - FB PHP SDK

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a question for Facebook App Developers :)

Is it possible to like a comment created by some user on any fanpage, via access_token and post request?

I read from https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/object/likes that it should be possible, however I can't find a way to figure out how to get an object ID of a comment.

Should I use in my fb.api request - postid_commentid as an object id?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You guess it right. The `comment_id` that you obtained as `postid_commentid` cann be used as the `{object-id}`. So simply make the call-

```
\POST /comment_id/likes
```

and the comment will be liked.

PS. you can always test the API call in [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer)

Hope that helps!